# Make part of layout invisible and the other part visible

Tags: android, layout

I would like to make a LinearLayout that was created from xml invisible, and another LinearLayout visible to replace it.  The replacement layout starts out as invisible. When I make the originally visible layout invisible, it still leaves space for it on the screen.  How can I refresh the screen so that space is gone?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you are mixing up `View.INVISIBLE` with `View.GONE`:

> [`int GONE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#GONE) This view is invisible, and it doesn't take any space for layout purposes.
>
> [`int INVISIBLE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#INVISIBLE) This view is invisible, but it still takes up space for layout purposes.

Comment: I didn't know GONE existed.  Thanks, I'm still brand new to Android

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before and its actually very simple. Make 2 different layout xml files, one for each layout you want to show. When you want to switch from one to the other, all you have to do is call `setContentView(R.layout.some_layout)` and you're done!

pretty easy eh?